# how to view all session variables in a current session

Tags: php, session, yii2

Currently am printing session like this

```
$session   = Yii::$app->session;

echo'<pre>';print_r($session);die;
```

and the result is

```
yii\web\Session Object
(
    [flashParam] => __flash
    [handler] => 
    [_cookieParams:yii\web\Session:private] => Array
        (
            [httponly] => 1
        )

    [_hasSessionId:yii\web\Session:private] => 
    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
)
```

but i need to print all variables in a session is there any way in yii2???

Comment: `echo "<pre>"; die(var_dump($_SESSION))`

Comment: object(yii\web\Session)#70 (6) {
  ["flashParam"]=>
  string(7) "__flash"
  ["handler"]=>
  NULL
  ["_cookieParams":"yii\web\Session":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["httponly"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["_hasSessionId":"yii\web\Session":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_events":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["_behaviors":"yii\base\Component":private]=>
  NULL
}
 now its printing like this

Comment: Am assigned some variables to session. i need that variables

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $session->set('user_id', '1234');
    foreach ($session as $session_name => $session_value){
        echo $session_name.' - '.json_encode($session_value);
        echo "<br>";
    }die;
```

Note : 
1) Here `$session_value` might be array so i have json encoded to echo it.

2) i have set user_id before displaying so that you can get this value along with all your session variables to verify